# format(x, d) not working mysql function

Tags: mysql, sql

I've following sql query in `MySQL` to return result with 2 decimal places.

```
FORMAT(((sold_amt - purchased_amt) * 5 / 100 * sold_qty), 2)
```

It is working fine when it is used in Store Procedure. But when it is used in `MySQL Function`, it doesn't give the expected result. Instead it gives all the decimal values. Does `FORMAT(x, d)` work in `MySQL Function`?

My full code for MySQL Function is :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `get_capital_gain`(purchased_amt FLOAT, sold_amt FLOAT, sold_qty INT(5)) 
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    IF sold_amt > purchased_amt THEN
        RETURN FORMAT(((sold_amt - purchased_amt) * 5 / 100 * sold_qty), 2);
    ELSE 
        RETURN 0.00;
    END IF; 
END$$
```

Comment: `FORMAT` returns a string. You have your function declared to return a float. So the string is being converted to a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It returns a string rather than a float, so the formatting will be kept.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
FUNCTION `get_capital_gain`(purchased_amt FLOAT, sold_amt FLOAT, sold_qty INT(5)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
    IF sold_amt > purchased_amt THEN
        RETURN FORMAT(((sold_amt - purchased_amt) * 5 / 100 * sold_qty), 2);
    ELSE 
        RETURN '0.00';
    END IF; 
END$$
```